# Can't add iPhone to Provisioning portal

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning

I have a new certificate installed. I want to add my iPhone to its profile, but in Xcode when I select "Add device to provisioning portal...", it goes through the process and displays its status, but when it says "Generating team provisioning profile", I get the error"

"An unexpected error has occurred, if the problem persists, contact Apple Developer support".

I've sent them a message, but haven't heard back. Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

I should also say that I am a lone developer. I don't work in a "team", as the status message suggests.

Comment: Everybody is a team to Apple.  Be patient, they're usually pretty good about getting back to you.  Just bear in mind that you're not the only person in their queue :)

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same problem and a workaround that worked for me was:

-use [provisioning portal](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) to create and edit provisioning profiles
-download and open the file
-provisioning certificate should show up in your XCode Organiuser now (apple-shift-O)

hope it helps :)